# Can't boot Windows 10 from GRUB

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, bios, zorin

When I installed Zorin OS (which is based on Ubuntu) with dual boot windows after boot it went straight into Windows 10. I took a look at the bios boot order and it was the following.

- Windows Boot Manager (NE-256)
- UEFI: PXE IP4 Realtek PCIe GBE Famimly Controller
- UEFI: Built- in EFI Shell
- NE-256
- Realtek PXE B01 D00
- Enter Setup

I rearranged the order and moved NE-256 to the top so it boots into Zorin, now I get into the grub menu but when I select Windows in this menu it goes back to my Bios logo screen and won't load windows it goes back to GRUB.

I can't seem to boot Windows from GRUB? Any ideas? I can boot Windows when selecting Windows Boot Manager (NE-256) however.

[image: https://imgur.com/jmrklpg]

Answer (score 0):

Appears I had installed Zorin in legacy mode, my BIOS supported both. I booted Zorin OS Live USB in UEFI mode and ran Boot Repair, this reinstalled grub. Since my first boot entry was set to the Legacy Boot Loader I was met was this after first restart

[image]

I then checked the boot entries and appears I now had a new ubuntu entry which was the new grub where I could boot both Zorin and Windows (UEFI) but I couldn't select this as my first boot option in my BIOS settings, it wasn't an option. It was installing booting to legacy.

On Windows what i did then was run `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` this sets the default boot loader to grub and boots directly to GRUB where both Zorin and Windows can launch.